# How do I render components in React Native based on an object from an API call whose values change depending on the exact API call?

Tags: javascript, json, react-native, api, schema

I am working on a React Native app that makes API calls from https://www.dnd5eapi.co/ and one of the things I want to do is when the user selects a certain monster it populates the page with the information about that monster from the API. What I am trying to figure out is what is the best way to create the component that displays this information? The problem I am having is depending on which monster is selected the values of the object that the API provides changes. I am not sure what the best way to deal with this would be. The API documentation does provide a Schema for the object but I am not sure how much it helps. https://www.dnd5eapi.co/docs/#get-/api/monsters/-index-

Answer (score 0):

first, fetch and render all monsters in a page or component, then on press on item render another page or component.
then, fetch monster details from api in `useEffect`

```
// parent component
const handleMonster=id=>event=>{ navigate('monster_details_page',{index})}
 return <>
    {monsters.map(monster=>(<View id={monster.index} onPress={handleMonster(monster.index)}}>
    // render moster list item here...
   </View>))}
</>

// details component
const route = useRoute();
const [monster,setMonster]=React.useState()
useEffect(()=>{// fetchMoster from `/api/monsters/${route.params.index}` and setMonster( // response from api) },[])
if(!monster) return <Text>Loading...</Text>
return (<View>// render your monster here</View>)
```